# Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY MySQL mode only for a user or database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

A short one: is it possible to **disable / turn off** SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` persistently, but **only for a user** and / or a **database**?

I have several databases and several independent users in my MySQL 5.7 server, and only one of them needs `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to be disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: They do not *need* for `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to be disabled.  They may want that, but it is better for them to rewrite their legacy queries.

Comment: Nope. There's no feature in MySQL that supports that. But a session can modify sql_mode for the session. Executing the required statement i.e. `SET sql_mode =` could be part of the connection pool initialization, or if we're running mysql command line client, as an `--init-command`. I would investigate that approach.

Comment: Thanks to both. Unfortunately, I need a solution, so I will investigate Spencer's approach.

Comment: I second Gordon Linoff's comment. I just dealt with this today. One of the developers wanted to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, and I was able to talk him out of it. I asked him to demonstrate the query he said he needed it for, and I rewrote his query so it would work without using GROUP BY at all. Relying on SQL queries that produce ambiguous results is not a good habit.